# I need a software for taking pictures from video 1 second after the picture has been changed

Tags: video, automation, live-preview

I need a video software that can make a picture every time when in the video (live, from camera for example) the picture is changed.

For example we have a scale so when there is nothing on it the picture is "frozen" but when we have something the picture will change to something so for the scale it needs about a second to get "stable" (the weight) so after that second I need that exact frame to be pictured and saved in some folder. So when the thing is taken of the scale the value will return 0 so another picture should be taken and so on...

I need a software that would take this pictures automatically. It is not important on what OS would be. If its for Windows fine. If Linux I will migrate but is also fine. I would be happy if its free but even if its paid I would like first to see that is the one I need (hopefully with trial or demo) and if so, then I will pay for it.

Comment: It occurs to me that if your example (the scale) is literally what you're trying to measure, a hard wait of exactly one second may be far less useful than you'd hope.   If it takes me a bit longer to actually get the object on the scale than normal, or if I put it down more roughly than normal, it could take more than a second from the moment the object enters the frame to stabilize the weight.

Comment: So if one second is not enought that can be changed to two second for example if possible

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you should be able to code something yourself if you are using a simple webcam for the video.  In a loop wait 1 second, then run a utility like `fswebcam` (usually a standard package in most Linux distributions), to take a single jpg or png picture, and then use `ImageMagick` to compare the last 2 images. Eg, if `old.jpg` and `new.jpg` are the 2 jpg files, then

```
compare -fuzz 10% -metric ae old.jpg new.jpg null:
```

will print a single number saying how many pixels differ between the images, ignoring small errors (eg 10%). When this number is sufficiently small your image is stable and you can use either of the images as the weight:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f new.jpg old.jpg
stable=0
while :
do    sleep 1
      fswebcam new.jpg
      if [ -s old.jpg ]
      then diff=$(compare -fuzz 10% -metric ae old.jpg new.jpg null:)
           if [ "$diff" -lt 100 ]
           then if [ $stable = 0 ]
                then echo "stable, first image"
                     stable=1
                fi
           else stable=0
           fi
      fi
      mv new.jpg old.jpg
done
```